# How to work around the CORS issue in Surface API from mapbox?

Tags: ajax, api, cors, mapbox

I am trying to use the [Surface API](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/surface/) by Mapbox to analyze the terrain between two given points. I am taking the coordinates of the two points and sending an AJAX call to the API but I am stuck with the infamous CORS issue.

To start with I am trying to use the URL provided by Mapbox itself in its examples:

```
$('#runTerrainAnalysis').on('click', function(e){
    var url = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/surface/mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v1.json?layer=contour&fields=ele&points=-112.084004,36.05322;-112.083914,36.053573;-112.083965,36.053845&access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoicm9oYW4wNzkzIiwiYSI6IjhFeGVzVzgifQ.MQBzoHJmjH19bXDW0b8nKQ';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/surface/mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v1.json?layer=contour&fields=ele&points=-112.084004,36.05322;-112.083914,36.053573;-112.083965,36.053845&access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoicm9oYW4wNzkzIiwiYSI6IjhFeGVzVzgifQ.MQBzoHJmjH19bXDW0b8nKQ. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

How do get this to work?

Comment: Try to include: `crossDomain: true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can send cross domain AJAX requests using JSONP. Below is the simple JSONP Request:

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    dataType:"jsonp",
});
```

**[Source](http://hayageek.com/cross-domain-ajax-request-jquery/)**

Working like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox API supports [cross-origin requests](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/#cors) with no domain restrictions, so it must be related to jquery.

Try to include `crossDomain: true`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    crossDomain: true,
    method: 'GET',
```

Comment: I've made a test here (with your data) with angularjs, and the return is **_"Feature not enabled. Please read https://www.mapbox.com/blog/introducing-the-surface-api
 for more information."_**

Comment: Yes the public key is not correct, but even then I should get the error your are getting. I tried the correct public key as well. I have tried it using Postman REST client and I can see the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *` header coming back which means it is enabled and the result is also as expected. But when I try it using my jquery, it doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you've not yet requested access to the Surface API (it is currently in private beta). This:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var url = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/surface/mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v1.json?layer=contour&fields=ele&points=-112.084004,36.05322;-112.083914,36.053573;-112.083965,36.053845&access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoicm9oYW4wNzkzIiwiYSI6IjhFeGVzVzgifQ.MQBzoHJmjH19bXDW0b8nKQ';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
</script>
```

returns the expected result:

```
{"message":"Feature not enabled. Please read https://www.mapbox.com/blog/introducing-the-surface-api for more information."}
```

You can request access at the bottom of this page: https://www.mapbox.com/blog/introducing-the-surface-api/